bitcoin rpc: bitcoin-cli positive fee
Using bitcoin RPC bitcoin-cli
commands like:

listtransactions
gettransaction

can fee ever be positive?

The fee is always negative
See https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/gettransaction.html

fee" : n,                               (numeric) The amount of the fee in BTC. This is negative and only available for the
'send' category of transactions.


Thanks a lot dear sir. Exactly but
I found some transactions in some watch-only wallets (I used descriptors) that if I check the txid in a bitcoin explorer I get a correct negative fee yet checking them using gettransaction or listtransactions in bitcoin-cli results in positive fees.
Can you provide some hints?

Do you have an example txid?

6e5fb370d70249246d53ea7aaa483a551d2e194a99b732eb8e7700f29d3c621f
there are several others
